How to use export and satisfies without default?
Consider the following module:
import type { Command, Commander, Options } from "zap";
import { Option, command } from "zap";

const name: string = "single";

const options: Options = {
  name: Option.string(),
};

const commander: Commander = async ({ values }) => {
  console.log(`single file command for ${values.name}`);
};

export { commander, name, options } satisfies Command;

Of course, the last line is causing a syntax error.
I know I can use export default like so:
export default { commander, name, options } satisfies Command;

Just wondering if it is possible to do it without default.

You can separately export each method/variable. export const name ... , export const options ... , export const commander ...

But then how do I check those exports all satisfy a certain type?

You're essentially looking for ms/TS#38511 which has not been implemented, so you'll need to work around it. Note that after export, { commander, name, options } is not an object, it just looks like object literal shorthand syntax. So it's not really an expression of type Command. The workaround here might look like this, but it's redundant. Does that fully address the question (even though it's not satisfying)? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?
